# How can I generation sine function faster in c

Tags: c

Is there anyway in which i can compute sine function faster in c.When i generate a sine waveform with 16,384 samples it is taking me 3.96 seconds and I want it less than 1 sec.

Give below is the logic i used for sine wave  and it is taking almost 4 seconds to compute.I  also tried optimization of the code but its of no help.

Someone please help me out

```
int i;
float f,temp = (2 * M_PI) /16384

for(i=0;i<16384;i++)
{
    f = sin(temp * i);
}
```

Comment: This loop takes no time at all in my machine. Even if I change it to `f += sin(temp * i);` to avoid compiler optimizations.

Comment: You can also try using addition instead of multiplication inside the for loop. Are you compiling optimized code and not debugging?

Comment: You might also want to refer to this: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4779/is-there-a-faster-sine-function

Comment: What @lhf said... I am suspecting a serious case of XY problem here: *Something* is taking 4 seconds to compute, but since I'm getting execution times in the thousandth-of-a-second range for this code (with `gcc -O0`), I am guessing your problem is elsewhere, so an answer to this question might not help you at all...

Comment: You must have a very bad computer and/or compiler.  It runs in .031 seconds on my old, cheap laptop (adding up the sines as @lhf did to prevent optimizations. If you have no options and are always sampling at these angles, just use a lookup table of 16384 constants.

Comment: On what kind of computer is this programm running ? Sounds to me like some very slow microcontroller.

Comment: What do you do with `f` after you assign the result of `sin` to it?  You wouldn't happen to be writing values to a file or standard output, would you?

Comment: Use `float sinf(float x)` .

Comment: `I am then converting this value to integer by 8192 + (8192 * f) and will send to the register to generate a sine waveform in the signal generator.`

Comment: Did you even try googling "fast sine"?

Answer (score 4):

There's no reason that you have to compute `f` more than once, *ever*. If performance is so critical, hardcode the array of values into the source.

Comment: Calculating a value is in many occasions, faster than accessing a large array.

Comment: The correct thing to do is to measure to identify the bottleneck. Though I would not call an array of 16k floats especially large.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point can be very slow in embedded implementations, but I don't believe it can be slower to index an array. This will create a C source file to `#include` in the project. I presume OP wanted an unsigned integer table, modify if not what was wanted. If you want to save on code space, code only the first quadrant and do a simple runtime adjustment of the lookup index and value for the other quadrants.

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES 1
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define TRIGPOINTS  16384
#define AMPLITUDE   8192.0
//#define M_PI        3.14159265358979323846

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fout;
    char *filename = "sinetable.c";
    int i;
    double d;
    if( (fout = fopen( filename, "w" )) == NULL ) {
        printf( "The file '%s' was not opened\n", filename );
        exit (1);
        }
    fprintf (fout, "#define TRIGPOINTS  %u\n", TRIGPOINTS);
    fprintf (fout, "#define AMPLITUDE   %f\n", AMPLITUDE);
    fprintf (fout, "\unsigned sintab [%u] = { ", TRIGPOINTS);
    for (i=0; i<TRIGPOINTS; i++)
        {
        if (i)
            fprintf (fout, ", ");
        if ((i % 10) == 0)
            fprintf (fout, "\n    ");
        d = AMPLITUDE + AMPLITUDE * sin(2.0 * M_PI * (double)i / TRIGPOINTS);
        fprintf (fout, "%u", (unsigned)d);
        }
    fprintf (fout, " };\n");
    fclose (fout);
    return (0);
}
```

The C source generated looks like this:

```
#define TRIGPOINTS  16384
#define AMPLITUDE   8192.000000
unsigned sintab [16384] = { 
    8192, 8195, 8198, 8201, 8204, 8207, 8210, 8213, 8217, 8220, 
    8223, 8226, 8229, 8232, 8235, 8239, 8242, 8245, 8248, 8251, 
    ...
```